# Django form wizard uploading files

Tags: python, django

I've made a FileWizard and on the last page I'd like to have a form to upload files.  Reading the documentation makes me doubt this is an easy thing to do. My initial thought is to, in the done method, grab the data and pass it into a different form, that will then accept the uploaded files before sending an email.

Is this possible?  Is there a better way?

Comment: I think your question is a bit difficult to understand. Because it is very easy to upload files to Django (Is this what you are asking?, and a way to notify via email once this is complete?)